# Formatting a Widget with Wordpress theme using custom CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, formatting, format, footer

got myself in a tight spot here, the widget on the right hand side of my website has lost its formatting, i need it all in one line, and to drop below the left hand widget when viewed in mobile: https://aurexgroup.com/

Im using a enfold child theme on a wordpress site.

i assume its a css issue, but i cant find the code that relates.
i have looked through the css style sheet in the theme, this is all i could for widgets find:

```
}
#top li.sf-widget-element{
list-style: none;
clear: none;
margin-left: 0;
padding: 0;
width:auto;
display:inline-block;
margin-right: 30px;
}
```

And then this in the quick css section in the enfold general styling tab:

```
}
#footer .flex_column{
float: right;
}
#footer .flex_column.first{
float: left;
}
.footer_color a, .footer_color .widget_first{
color: #cf5c1a !important;
}
#footer .flex_column .widget{
margin-top: 0;
margin-bottom: 0;
line-height: 26px;
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;
}
.copyright a[href*="kriesi"]{
display:none !important;
}
```

Very open to any ideas!
please help!

Comment: I do not see a widget on the right-hand side on the link provided

Comment: the widget is the 
"Contact Aurex Group | Privacy Policy | © Copyright – Aurex Group 2018" block in the footer?